# SQL error in where clause COUNT()

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a chat, and i dont want any messages with 5+ reports. The reports are stored in `table reports`.

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT *, 
   message_id                               AS current_id, 
   (SELECT Count(report_id) 
    FROM   reports 
    WHERE  report_messages_fk = current_id) AS report_count 
FROM   messages 
   INNER JOIN users 
           ON message_user_fk = users.id 
WHERE  report_count < 5 
ORDER  BY message_date ASC 
LIMIT  100
```

This sql work without the `WHERE report_count < 5`, but not with it.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Replacing the `WHERE` clause with and `HAVING clause fixed the issue, thanks.`

Comment: What is the specific information about the error it's throwing? Error number?

Comment: You cannot use a column alias in a `where` clause.  Use a `having` clause insetad.

Comment: This is the errorcode: #1054

Comment: Should i move the subqurey to the having clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT -- *, replace with appropriate column names
message_id AS current_id, 
Count(report_id) as report_count
FROM  messages 
INNER JOIN users ON messages.message_user_fk = users.id 
INNER JOIN reports on reports.report_messages_fk = messages.current_id
group by message_id
having Count(report_id) < 5
```

Your query has been modified by including `join` on the `reports` table as well. Also you have to include your condition in the `having` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` to filter results after they've already been processed.

Source:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/04/sql-server-definition-comparison-and-difference-between-having-and-where-clause/